# How to use ax.tick_params to hide x-axis labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to hide the label on my x-axis but I don't get it correctly.

Originally I used this code to plot my data:

```
df.plot(x='_time', y='IdCount', kind='bar')
```

Then, I got the hint to use `ax.tick_params` and to set:

```
ax = df.plot(x='_time', y='IdCount', kind='bar')
```

I read the documentation of `ax.tick_params` but I do not get it how I could hide my labels...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ax.set_xtickslabel([])`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1],[0,1])
ax.set_xticklabels([])
```

Output:

[image]